# Json Dumps doesn't parse correctly emojis unicode

Tags: python, json, unicode

We are getting a json file from whatsapp contact to process in Aws Glue.
In username we have lot of emojis and Glue fails each time to process the json.

We noticed that when doing json dumps when we create the json file, some emojis are converted to unicode
For example `LE JOOCHAR`  is converted to `LE JOOCHAR \U0001f90c`

Because of the unicode `\U0001f90c` Glue doesn't succeed to parse the file.

We tried lot of solutions

```
string_data = string_data.replace('\U0001f90c', '\u0001f90c')
```

Not working. The Unicode is not even replaced in the string.

```
contact_response_obj = json.dumps(contact_response_obj, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
```

Not working, always have this unicode character

Please how could we do to remove or convert correctly this unicode ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The replacement code must escape the backslashes or use raw strings: `string_data = string_data.replace(r'\U0001f90c', r'\u0001f90c')`

Comment: Are you sure it's working?  The `\u` (lowercase u) is only going to take the next 4 hex characters, leaving you with a 5 character string instead of just the single emoji.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes it is working. The file is accepted by the Glue processor. I think the system was not able to convert the `\U000` and expecting lowercase. I don't know why there is a uppsercase for this emoji. My main concern is now how to detect a Uppercase without waiting for a next failures of my requests ?

Comment: Uppercase `\U` is used for large codepoints over 4 digits, and lowercase `\u` is used for those that fit into 4 digits.  But if you look at the [ECMA-404 JSON specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf) page 5, it says that only the lower-case form can be used and that larger codepoints must be broken into surrogate pairs, resulting in two `\u`  sequences.

Comment: P.S. "being accepted" is not the same as "doing the correct thing".

Comment: _"when doing json dumps, some emojis are converted to unicode"_ No. When using [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps), **all** emojis are converted to unicode.

Comment: @MarkRansom you were right. When i check how Glue interprets the string I have this `LE JOOCHAR f90c`. So even if it is parsed, the result is not "correct".

Comment: The question contains precious little code, and no details on the error received. I provided an answer based on what looked like a clear JSON syntax error, but you say it didn't help. This question may be unanswerable in its current form.

Comment: I suspect that something else is happening somewhere in the pipeline, and there is insufficient information to pinpoint it. `json.dumps()` will not generate the C style escapes being reported in the question. The problem is likely elsewhere in the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `ensure_ascii` parameter.  If you leave it off, the default is `True` and `json.dumps` will do the right thing.

```
contact_response_obj = json.dumps(contact_response_obj).encode('ascii')
```

Your output will be larger if you have a lot of non-ASCII characters, but it should be universally compatible everywhere.

Comment: I tried your solution. It is not working.

Comment: @TeddyKossoko have you looked at the output?  Any more detail than "not working"?

Comment: the unicode is still in the json. They are not converted and Aws still refuse the json.

Comment: @TeddyKossoko when I try it I get `\ud83e\udd0c` instead of `\U0001f90c`, which is valid JSON by the spec. What do you get?

Comment: I Get this `f90c`. I finally delete in my json the column with the user name. I spent so many days on it without solutions.